# Adding new elements to an enumerated type

Tags: delphi, types, enumeration

Given an enumerated type declaration in Delphi such as:

```
TMyType = (Item1, Item2, Item3);
```

is there any way to add a fourth item, say Item4, to the enumerate type at *runtime* so that 
at some point during the application's execution I have:

```
TMyType = (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4);
```

Or are types fixed in Delphi?

Comment: I wonder who ever would want to extend or alter any type during runtime. What purpose would it serve? It just is impossible to chance a type at runtime. I don't think there is a language, even the weakest/dynamically typed, that offers that abbility.

Comment: Do you need this for injection? An update? What kind of items are in this enum? Don't you just need a TList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you 'can't' do this. It is against the way Delphi works. (Recall that Delphi checks your types already at compile time.)

If I were you, I'd *not* do

```
TComputerType = (ctDesktop, ctServer, ctLaptop, ctNetbook, ctTablet)
```

Instead, I'd do

```
TComputerType = integer;

const
  COMPUTER_TYPE_DESKTOP = 0;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_SERVER = 1;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_LAPTOP = 2;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_NETBOOK = 3;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_TABLET = 4;
```

I am sure you get why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I suspected this was the case but wanted to check anyway. I thought maybe there might have been a RTTI trick. I am now using a list of constants as you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a `set`.

The following example initializes the set with items `item1` and `item4`.
After that `item5` is added.
It shows whether item5 is in the set, before and after adding, so you'll get this output:

```
FALSE
TRUE
```

Example:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

type
  TMyType = (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5,Item6);
const
  cItems1And4 : set of TMyType = [Item1,Item4];
var
  MyItems:set of TMyType;

begin
  MyItems := cItems1And4;
  WriteLn(Item5 in MyItems);
  Include(MyItems,Item5);
  WriteLn(Item5 in MyItems);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

...

I wanted to type the following as a comment to Andreases reply, but the comment system doesn't let me properly format stuff..

If you're not stuck with an ancient Delphi, this is probably a better idea:

```
  TComputerType = record
    const
      Desktop = 0;
      Server = 1;
      Netbook = 2;
      Tabled = 3;
  end;
```

That makes sure you don't pollute your namespace, and you'll get to use it as if it's a scoped enum:

```
 TComputerType.Netbook
```

I usually do it like that nowadays.. You can even create some handy helper-functions or properties in there, for example to convert from and to strings.

Comment: Interesting, it did cross my mind to use sets. I like your suggestion for including the names in a record to avoid namespace clashes. One of the items was actually named tExt which of course clashes with text ! I'm going to use your suggestion, wish I could give you an extra useful point.

Comment: I don't get the set idea. After all, sets and enumerations are two different concepts, and, as far as I can imagine, there is never any doubt whether a variable should be of an enum or a set type...

Comment: I'm with Andreas, a set is not a replacement for an enumeration. Here's an enumeration, `TAnimal = (Mouse, Fox, Owl, Snake, Gruffalo)`.  Imagine that as a set. What would it mean for something to be both Mouse and Gruffalo?

Comment: FWIW, the newest Delphis allow scoped enums, i.e. in David's example, you'd have to qualify TAnimal.Fox, TAnimal.Owl, etc. These do not pollute the global namespace. I agree with Andreas: a set won't change the problem. Single constants are the way to go, if it must be extendable.

Comment: Scoped enums are enabled with {$SCOPEDENUMS ON}. An enumeration defined that way **must** be qualified with the type name. One can't use Owl or Fox, only TAnimal.Owl and TAnimal.Fox are valid.

Comment: @David: it would cause a serious identity crisis, that's what it would mean. <g>

Comment: @David: Yeah, of course sets are a different concept, but in pascal this is the closest you can get to what Rhody asks for, and I thought that this is what he actually meant. Changing type definitions during runtime, with a compiled and strongly typed language doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Rudy: Indeed, I find having {$SCOPEDENUMS ON} a good practice (less confusion, more readable, code-completion works nicer, less namespace pollution), but if you're giving up the type-safety of enums, you should at least consider packing your constants into a struct or a class.  It's cleaner and more powerful than global constants if you need properties or custom attributes per item.

Comment: But if you pack the constants in a record type, they are not extensible anymore. You could pack them in a class, but that feels weird.

Comment: Using record constats seem to be an elegant solution to the COMPUTER_TYPE_... name pollution. +1 for that alone.

Answer (score 3):

Types are fixed at compile time in Delphi—it is, after all, a statically typed language.

You can, at compile time, define [subranges](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Subrange_Types) of an enumeration:

```
type
  TEnum = (item1, item2, item3, item4);
  TSubRangeEnum = item1..item3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot yet comment, I will add one addendum to what Andreas suggested that might help if you have many such lists to maintain.  Adding a "base" constant for each grouping might help keep them better organized within your code and help with debugging the constants later (assuming each group has a unique base, of course).

```
TComputerType = integer;

const
  COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE = 100;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_DESKTOP = COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE + 1;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_SERVER = COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE + 2;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_LAPTOP = COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE + 3;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_NETBOOK = COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE + 4;
  COMPUTER_TYPE_TABLET = COMPUTER_TYPE_BASE + 5;
```